# Facebook Built-in Like action callback

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Facebook recently introduced the "Built-in Like" as a built-in Open Graph action (see [blogpost](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/bringing-like-to-mobile/) and [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/)). I would like to implement this functionality in my iOS App and be able to listen to the event, when the user completes the like action (similarly to using [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) in JavaScript). Is this posible and how would you accomplish this?

Comment: Nice piece of information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you linked:

> To publish a built-in Like action on an Open Graph object, invoke the following HTTP POST request with a user’s access token and the url
> of the Open Graph object. This Open Graph object can be of any type.
>
> [example snipped]
>
> which in turn will return the ID of the built-in Like action instance if the call is successful`

The API call itself, which your app makes, will return the ID of the newly created object, there's no special or separate callback - your own code is creating the Like action.